# How Can i Run jboss EAP-7.0.0 as windows service on windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows, service, jboss, jboss7.x

I have installed Jboss EAP-7.0.0 on windows 7 x64 operating system.

When i run Jboss EAP-7.0.0 via standalone.bat file inside bin direcotry it starts without any problem and deployed .war files also work without any problem, but when i try to run `serice.bat install` command  inside bin direcotry it gives following output in console: `Please install native utilities into expected location D:\jboss EAP-7.0.0\EAP-7.0.0\..\jbcs-jsvc-1.0`

I tried googling this issue. I also tried to follow this link: [Failed to start EAP 7 as Windows service.](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2784941) (you might need to login on in webpage to see whole discussion) and this link [4.3. CONFIGURING JBOSS EAP AS A SERVICE IN MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/paged/installation-guide/chapter-4-configuring-jboss-eap-to-run-as-a-service) but the products dropdown is empty (please see the image)

I am really confused and need your help: How do i download and install jbcs-jsvc-1.0  ?

[image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you have to log in to the Red Hat Customer Portal JBoss Software Downloads [page](https://access.redhat.com/jbossnetwork/restricted/listSoftware.html), in order to download and install the **JBoss Core Services Jsvc** package.

After downloading the appropriate zip file (latest version, correct platform and architecture), extract it into the directory "containing" your JBoss EAP installation directory. In other words, the new "jbcs-jsvc-" directory should be at the same depth as your JBoss EAP installation directory.

Then, go on and install the service the same as EAP 6.x

Comment: Yes, but i am logged in. On screenshot  i have uploaded, on top right corner you can see that customer portal says my name and surname. Maybe i am missing someething?

Comment: Since you are logged in, go on and select "Apache Jsvc" in the Product drop-down menu. Be sure to select the latest version from the Version drop-down menu. Then you can find "Red Hat JBoss Core Services Apache Jsvc" in the list. Just bear in mind to select the correct platform and architecture for your system.

Comment: But as i mentioned and the screenshot i provided in my answer shows that the product dropdown is empty, how or where do i select one?

Comment: I am afraid this has to do with your credentials. As far as I can understand, you are not eligible to download this software due to your subscription with Red Hat.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer:** I didn't confirm this on Windows 7 but it works under Windows Server 2016. I.e. since there shouldn't be any relevant difference, it should be fine.

---

The `service.bat` included in JBoss EAP 7 expects a `prunserv.exe` at one of the following locations:

- `%JBOSS_HOME%\..\jbcs-jsvc-1.0\sbin\prunsrv.exe` or
- `%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\prunsrv.exe`

If you don't have the proper subscription/permission to download the *JBoss Core Services Jsvc* (e.g. because you just have a developer subscription), you can just download the `prunsrv.exe` as part of the freely available Apache commons-daemon package:

1. Download "commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows.zip", e.g. from
   http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/apache/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/
2. Unzip it into the `%JBOSS_HOME%\bin` folder
3. Run `service.bat install`

Instead of an error message, you get notified that your Windows Service has been successfully installed as "JBossEAP7" (unless you already have one with that name).

Comment: how can i run service.bat install ? in where location ?

Comment: @يعقوب as per the OP: it's supposed to be in the `bin` folder

Comment: thanks @Carsten, i found it in JBOSS_HOME\docs\contrib\scripts\service for wildfly 28.