# How to configure JBoss EAP as windows service

Tags: jboss

I installed JBoss EAP-7.1.0 through windows installer. Now i want to configure this EAP as windows service. How can i do this? I went through several docs but didn't get a proper idea. After that i need to access the admin-console ui of the server. Can some one help?

Comment: You can check the documantation:https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/installation_guide/configuring_jboss_eap_to_run_as_a_service#configuring_jboss_eap_as_a_service_in_microsoft_windows_server

Comment: I followed the documentation, but i couldn't download the Apache Jsvc (In the product drop down nothing is listed)

Comment: I got the reason, it's because I doesn't have sufficient subscription in RedHat Customer portal. (only have developer subscription)

Comment: Similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995376/how-can-i-run-jboss-eap-7-0-0-as-windows-service-on-windows-7-x64 . This is worked.